# Ubuntu server - Problem of routing

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, routing, gateway

I have setup a Ubuntu server with Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud. The server is connected to a private LAN with DHCP and Internet access (via a gateway).

At first, the server was working fine. It can ping the internet. It can also ping other machine inside LAN.

The problem happened after i let the machine idle for more than 1 hour. When I want to use the machine again, I can't ping the internet anymore. I can only ping the machine inside LAN.

I try to ping the server from another machine and it's working. Then, i ssh into that server from another machine, and I found that I can ping the internet from that server.

It seems that there are some problems in the routing table of this server. Can anyone help me on this?

Thank you.

Max

Comment: for starters, you should print your routing table (run route from shell) before and after the problem starts.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely that the DHCP client is setting the default gateway, you can force it to use another one, but I don't see any way to ignore the one from DHCP.

To force one you can do, in `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`:

```
supersede routers 1.2.3.4;
```